# "Property description must be an object" error

Tags: javascript

Using this code I have this issue:

```
$.fn.dxwShow = function (options)
{
    console.log(typeof(options));
    dxwShowSetOptions(options);

    setInterval(function(){
        dxwShowChange();
    }, dxwShowOptions.time);
};

var dxwShowOptions = {
    "transition" : "SlideToggle",
    "time": 1000
};

var dxwShowStatus = {
    current : 0
};

function dxwShowSetOptions(options)
{
    console.dir(typeof(options));

    dxwShowOptions = Object.create(dxwShowOptions, options);
}

function dxwShowChange()
{
    console.log(dxwShowOptions);
};

$(function()
{
    options = {
        "time": 700,
        "debug" : true
    };

    $("#dxwShow").dxwShow(options);
});
```

I want to update `dxwShowOptions` and so I use `Object.create` passing first the object I wanna copy and so the object containing the new parameters. Where is the mistake?

PS :Chrome say that the object is at the `Object.create` line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Object.create` takes a map of property descriptors. `options` is not such a list.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

If you wanted to still use `Object.create`, you'd need to modify options to be something more like

```
var options = {
    time: {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: 700
    },
    debug: {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true,
        writable: true,
        value: true
    }
};
```

But probably you want to use something more like [`_.extend`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#extend).