# JavaScript - Dynamically loading a class and creating new instance with specific properties

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I have a Node.js v11.11.0 app. In this app, my files are structured like the following:

```
./src
  /animals/
    animal.js
    tiger.js
    koala.js
  index.js
```

As shown above, I have three classes defined in the `animals` directory. Over time, I intend to add additional animals with more complex logic. At this time, my classes are defined like so:

**animal.js**

```
'use strict';

class Animal {
  constructor(properties) {
    properties = properties || {};

    this.kind = 'Unknown';
  }

  eat(foods) {
    for (let i=0; i<foods.length; i++) {
      console.log(`Eating ${foods[i]}`);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Animal;
```

**tiger.js**

```
'use strict';

const Animal = require('./animal');

class Tiger extends Animal {
  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);

    this.kind = 'Tiger';
  }

  eat(foods) {
    for (let i=0; i<foods.length; i++) {
      if (foods[i].kind === 'meat') {
        console.log(`Eating ${foods[i]}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Tiger;
```

**koala.js**

```
'use strict';

const Animal = require('./animal');

class Koala extends Animal {
  constructor(properties) {
    super(properties);

    this.kind = 'Koala';
  }

  eat(foods) {
    for (let i=0; i<foods.length; i++) {
      if (foods[i].kind === 'plant') {
        console.log(`Eating ${foods[i]}`);
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports = Koala;
```

I am trying to dynamically create an instance of one of these classes based on what the user enters. For example, I'm doing this:

**index.js**

```
const readline = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
})

readline.question('What animal file do you want to load?', (fname) => {
  let properties = {
    name: 'My Pet'
  };

  let Animal = require(fname);
  let pet = Object.create(Animal.prototype, properties);
});
```

If I run this and enter `./animals/tiger.js`, I get an error. The error says: `Property description must be an object`. I don't understand this. Both `Tiger` and `Koala` extend `Animal`. At the same time, as my list will be dynamic, I need the free form option of typing a file path and dynamically loading the class. For that reason, I can't use the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655616/create-an-instance-of-a-class-in-es6-with-a-dynamic-name), which specifically lists the Class names.

How do I dynamically load a class and create an instance of that class with specific properties?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Property description must be an object" error in javascript. Can't understand why :(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032262/property-description-must-be-an-object-error-in-javascript-cant-understand-w)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second argument to `Object.create` is the same argument you would pass to `Object.defineProperties`, your `properties` is therefore invalid. Instead use Object.assign:

```
 Object.assign(Object.create(Animal.prototype), properties)
```

But why don't you just call the constructor?

```
 new Animal(properties)
```

---

Secondly this:

```
 properties = properties || {};
```

is probably intended to be:

```
 this.properties = properties || {};
```

---

And I wouldn't recommend to dynamically `require`, especially not from a user entered value, instead create a lookup object:

```
 const AnimalByName = {
   Bear: require("./Bear"),
   //...
 };

 const instance = new AnimalByName[name](properties);
```

Comment: +1 for the constructor point. Regarding your last point, what is the point of the lookup object? I don't think about "performances" as OP also requires dynamically. Is it for "UI" reasons (user needs to enter `Bear` instead of `./animals/Bear.js`?

Comment: @al-un there are various reasons, one would be the following animal: `../.../../secret/directory/password.json` ... additionally there are a lot of cases where the require would crash or create an invalid Animal, which then causes trouble later on.

Comment: The `new Animal(properties)` approach worked. Thank you.